# Arduino loop potentiometer light high and low

Tags: arduino, led

I am  try to build an ardunio application which i have a potentiometer and led. i create components like this : http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Tutorial/graph-circuit3.png

when i turn potentiometer left( or right) , let is light with high and low steps. I wrote codes, but i couldnt success. Get compile error at loop

The code:

```
int potPin = 2;  
     int ledPin = 8;   
int val = 0;       

 void setup() {       
   pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  
  }    
   void loop(){
    while (Serial.available() == 0); 
       int val = Serial.read() - '0'; 

    if (potPin == 2) { 
       Serial.println("LED on");
          digitalWrite(potPin, HIGH);
      }
      else
        {
          Serial.println("LED OFF");
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);                  
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

routine led  high and low which uses  potentiometer  like this foto potpin is 0.
You must create interim integer (i said val). val is store data came from potentiometer. and write val value to screen.

```
 int potPin = 0;  
int ledPin = 8;  
int val = 0;       
void setup()
 {  
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  
 }
void loop()
  {      
  val = analogRead(potPin);   
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); 

 delay(val);                    
     digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);        
 delay(val);                  
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the Serial.begin and pinMode of the potPin in the setup.

```
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(potPin, INPUT);
```

Also, you're trying to set the potPin on HIGH, while it is supposed to be an analog input.

Comment: Good point, but that wouldn't get him a compile error. He's also missing an end curly brace.